# How can I parse JSON string and print it using Python on linux?

Tags: python, json, linux

This is a pretty basic question, but I don't know Python at all and I ask you guys.

I want to parse a JSON string on Linux command `using Python`.
and I want to print if only the value of the `id` column in the JSON string is `"ok"`.

For example,

extected (1) -> if id == ok

```
$ echo '{"id": "ok", "name": "b"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; `blah blah blah.....'

{"id": "ok", "name": "b"}
```

extected (2) -> if id != ok

```
$ echo '{"id": "no", "name": "a"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; `blah blah blah.....'
(empty)
```

---

I tried many attempts to solve this problem, but all failed..

```
echo '{"id":"ok", "name": "a"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; d=sys.stdin; obj=json.load(d); print (d if obj["id"] == "ok" else "")'
<open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0x7fb6391060c0>
```

So I thought variable `d` is an object, not a value. So I tried to use `read()`.

```
echo '{"id":"ok", "name": "a"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; d=sys.stdin; obj=json.load(d); print (d.read() if obj["id"] == "ok" else "")'
(empty)
```

I don't know understand why nothing is printed..

Please help me T.T

Answer (score 1):

You're right about `d` being an object. You should output what was read in by `json.parse` instead:

```
echo '{"id":"ok", "name": "a"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; d=sys.stdin; obj=json.load(d); print (obj if obj["id"] == "ok" else "")'
```

If you want the output in standard JSON syntax change `obj` to `json.dumps(obj)`.

The reason your second solution does not work is because `json.parse` already read all the contents from stdin and `read()` does not reset the stream position (which is not possible for stdin to begin with).

Comment: Oh, thank you.. `echo '{"id":"ok", "name": "a"}' | python -c 'import json,sys; d=sys.stdin; obj=json.load(d); print (json.dumps(obj) if obj["id"] == "ok" else "")'` works well XD